# Pipe Symbol in qsub Job name

Tags: qsub, sungridengine

Is a pipe symbol allowed in SunGridEngine job name? I found a few reference stating not to use special characters in the name but I'm not sure if pipe symbol is part of the list.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried with OGS (descendant of SGE) and it works fine so I'm pretty sure it works in SGE as well. Make sure to enclose the job name into single quotes if you are trying this from the shell.

```
%> qsub -N 'co|co' -b y test.sh
Your job 438421 ("co|co") has been submitted
```